# How to copy color style preferences of Xcode 3.2.4 to Xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I had a great editor color theme for Xcode 3.2.4 which helped me coding at night. It took me a week to get that theme right.

I installed Xcode 4 in a new directory and kept Xcode 3.2.4 on my hard drive. Is there a way to import the Xcode 3.2.4 color theme in Xcode 4.2, such that I won't have to re-configure everything?

Comment: "It took me a week to get that theme right." Time well spent! :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Xcode color themes now use a new format. The defaults are provided by `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTKit.framework`. When you create your own, the selected default is duplicated and a `YourThemeName.dvtcolortheme` is created in your `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes` folder.

The theme files are in XML format with colors stored as RGBA values in a string:

```
...

    <key>DVTSourceTextSyntaxColors</key>
<dict>
    <key>xcode.syntax.attribute</key>
    <string>0.512 0.423 0.157 1</string>
...
```

I don't think there's a way to convert them directly. If it's truly that hard to recreate in the UI, you might consider creating and manually editing a custom theme.